# Como utilizar join en Postgres

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Tengo la **Tabla A:**

```
-------------------
*    fechaA       *
-------------------
* 2017-09-01      *
* 2017-09-02      *
* 2017-09-03      *
* 2017-09-04      *
* 2017-09-05      *
* 2017-09-06      *
* 2017-09-07      *
* 2017-09-08      *
* 2017-09-09      *
* 2017-09-10      *
-------------------
```

Y la **Tabla B**

```
-------------------
*    fechaB       *
-------------------
* 2017-09-01      *
* 2017-09-06      *
* 2017-09-10      *
-------------------
```

Y tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT fechaA       
FROM TABLA_A
WHERE fechaA NOT IN (SELECT FechaB FROM TABLA_B)
```

Que es la diferencia de **A** en **B**

El **Resultado es:**

```
-------------------
*    Resultado    *
-------------------
* 2017-09-02      *
* 2017-09-03      *
* 2017-09-04      *
* 2017-09-05      *
* 2017-09-07      *
* 2017-09-08      *
* 2017-09-09      *
-------------------
```

> El problema es que la consulta es mas larga que la que muestro y me gustaría hacerla mas eficaz esta con un `join`, el caso es que no se como hacerlo. Les agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Esto no es PostgREST (https://postgrest.org/en/stable/index.html), si no PostgreSQL. Habría que editar el título.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.fechaA
FROM TABLA_A a
LEFT JOIN TABLA_B b ON a.fechaA = b.fechaB
WHERE b.fechaB IS NULL
```

Referencia: https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Fundamentos-de-SQL-Operaciones-con-conjuntos.aspx